# Find table in firebase real time database given user email or some other arbitrary field

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a user stored in real time firebase with key `uid` (user id) and fields:

```
uid
email
emailVerfied
```

I would like to find the user record coresponding given an email. My current hack leaves much to be desired. In particular how to properly retrieve the actual user record given a `snapshot`:

```
function readByEmail( user_email : string, next : any ){

    firebaseApp.database().ref('/users/')
    .orderByChild('email')
    .equalTo(user_email)
    .once('value', snap => {

        // retrieve the user key:
        const record = snap.val();

        let key;

        for ( let _key in record ) {
            console.log('field: ', _key, record[_key])
            key = _key;
        }

        next(record[key])

    });
}
```

How should I get rid of the ugly loop hack which is not gauranteed to work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a child property `email` with the value you want to filter on, there may be multiple child nodes matching the value you filter in. That's why you need the loop, so I'd say that is working as expected.

A more idiomatic way of performing the loop is to use Firebase's built-in `forEach` method:

```
firebaseApp.database().ref('/users/')
.orderByChild('email')
.equalTo(user_email)
.once('value', snap => {

    let key;
    snap.forEach(child => {
        key = child.key;
    });

    next(snap.child(key).val())
});
```

If you know there is only one child that matches, you can listen for `child_added`, which fires for each child. So `once("child_added"` will fire only for the first child:

```
firebaseApp.database().ref('/users/')
.orderByChild('email')
.equalTo(user_email)
.once('child_added', snap => {
    next(snap.val())
});
```

But if your app already requires that the email value is unique amongst all nodes under `/users`, consider using the value as the key. You'll need to encode the email address, since `.` is not allowed in Firebase keys (encoding it as `,` is custom). When you use the (encoded) email address as the key, you can do a direct lookup like this:

```
firebaseApp.database().ref('/users/'+user_email)
.once('value', snap => {
    const record = snap.val();
    key = snap.key;

    next(record)
});
```

And since there's at most one node that matches this read, you no longer need a loop in the callback.